# Get Comment With Meta value

Tags: comment-form, comments

I need get all comments of a post including of the meta value..
for eg. i need all comments fields + a meta value.

i tried the following code to get but.. its not working

```
$args = array( 
  'status' => 'approve', 
  'type' => 'comment', 
  'post_id' => '99', 
  'post_type' => 'product', 
  //'count' => true, 
  'meta_query' => array( 
    array( 
      'key' => 'comment_rating_avg_key', 
      'compare' => 'EXISTS', 
    ), 
  ), 
); 
$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query; 
$comments = $comments_query->query( $args ); 
var_dump($comments);
```

Do i need to write a custom query to get it ?
or it can be done using default WP functions ?

Comment: "its not working" means what? Do you get results at all? Do you get the wrong results? What?

Comment: @s_ha_dum in the question i have mentioned that i need to get the comment along with the meta value. for which i have given in the code (Meta Query). i am getting the value for the comment. but not with the meta value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`WP_Comment_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query) doesn't pull comment meta. You can search by comment meta but the query doesn't return that data. You could easily check this yourself by looking at the Codex.

You need to loop over the results and run [`get_comment_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment_meta), or essentially do the same via a filter on [`the_comments`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-includes/class-wp-comment-query.php#L438).

It is also possible to add to the data returned by [filtering the "fields" clauses](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-includes/class-wp-comment-query.php#L810):

```
function add_cmeta_wpse_212423($clauses){
  //   var_dump($clauses);
  global $wpdb;
  $meta = "(SELECT meta_value
  FROM {$wpdb->commentmeta} 
  WHERE (
    comment_id = comment_ID
    AND meta_key = 'test_comment_meta')
  ) as test_comment_meta";
  $clauses['fields'] .=  ', '.$meta;
  return $clauses;
}
add_filter('comments_clauses','add_cmeta_wpse_212423');
```

I created a subquery. You could create a `JOIN` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to get comments count with buyer suggestion meta value in my recent woocommerce theme (buyer suggestion done with acf plugin).
to get the count of amount of all comments with buyer suggestion, below code worked for me. (sorry for my english, its not my native)

```
$args = array(
    'post_id' => get_the_ID(),
    'count'   => true,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'viuna-shop-comment-suggest-buying-product',
            'value' => 'i-suggest',
        ),
    ),
);

// The Comment Query
$comment_query = get_comments($args);
```

If `'count'   => true`, it returns only the comments number, if you want the list of comments, remove it.